# pushViewController doesnt work even though i have a navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have a UIViewController with two UITableView's in it. When i select a row in the first UITableView it has to push the same UIViewController which doesnt happen.

In UIViewController.h i have,

```
FirstTableViewController *firstController;
SecondTableViewController *secondController;
```

In UIViewController.m i have,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    if (firstController == nil) {
        firstController = [[FirstTableViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if (secondController == nil) {
        secondController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] init];
    }
    UINavigationController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];
    firstController.product = self.product;
    [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
    [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
    firstNavigationController.view = firstController.tableView;
}
```

In FirstTableViewController.m, didSelectRowAtIndexPath i have,

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
controller.product = prod;
NSLog(@"Navigation controller is %@",self.navigationController); //not null
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Please help.

EDIT #1: UIViewController is called from the FlipsideViewController of the UtilityApp.

Comment: Is `[self navigationController]` returning `nil`?

Comment: No. Its returning <UINavigationController: 0x6a7a000>

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your AppDelegate `UINavigationController *nav`
add this line to AppDelegate.m in application didFinishLaunching method

```
navigationControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourFirst ViewController];
```

Go to yourFirstViewController, add an `UINavigationController *nav` property and add these lines to viewDidLoad method

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.nav = app.nav;
```

Use this line to push any viewController

```
[self.nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: doesnt work because UIViewController is not my first ViewController. UIViewController is called from the FlipsideView of the UtilityApp.

Comment: Can you please check your viewController that is pushed is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a view controller modally, you should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and not `pushViewController:animated:`.

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Nope.. I need to push it.. as they are DetailViewControllers. And when i try to present it modally i get the following error                    Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: The controller you load isn't nil either?

Comment: No. Its <UIViewController: 0x689e880>

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];


     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

     [viewController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

LoginViewSimpleController *loginViewSimple = [[LoginViewSimpleController alloc]init];

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginViewSimple];

[self setNavigationController:navController];
```

Have you identify both tableviews ? Can you Post log status here ?